# How to format currency in Filemaker ExecuteSQL istruction?

Tags: filemaker

there is a way to format currencies in the result of an ExecuteSQL?

Sql keyword "FORMAT" doesn't work.

the calculation is:

```
ExecuteSQL ( "

SELECT expenses.user, ' - € ', SUM(expenses.value) 
FROM expenses 
GROUP BY expenses.user"
;" " ; ¶  ) ;
```

my output is

```
Ray - € 10000.1
John - € 44926.97
Tim - € 315.88
```

I need to get

```
Ray - € 10.000,10
John - € 44.926,97
Tim - € 315,88
```

Comment: I can not see FORMAT is being supported in FileMaker SQL and I do not think it is included in SQL-92 standard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is (sort of) possible to format a Number field, but not a sum - because an aggregate function cannot be used as an argument to other functions.

However, you *could* process the query result and format the amounts using Filemaker's native functions. Or (probably simpler) use a summary field instead of `ExecuteSQL()`.